# Can't parse ruby request params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am submitting a form in Ruby and want to check before submitting.

I can see the params hash in terminal which looks like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "email"=>"someone@gmail.com",...}
```

but eg params[:email] is null.

How do I pull that value?

In response to the first answer below, in my controller, I tried:

```
  puts "params:  #{params}"
  puts "params email:  #{params["email"]}"
  puts "params email:  #{params[:email]}"
  puts "params email:  #{params['email']}"
```

Here is the response in terminal:

> params:  {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch",
> "authenticity_token"=>"FNkGQg9+HmhMssJQTLUr29fejDyF9QORcvG1BMonJ7l2vwaPejM6x+pjlua90NFsXNAJGg/MUZWl97jnmBlutg==",
> "contact"=>{"name"=>"john smith", "phone"=>"",
> "email"=>"someone@gail.com", "image_url"=>"", "website"=>"",
> "location_info"=>"", "bio"=>"", "tag_ids"=>["", "Crypto", "home"],
> "category_ids"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Update Contact",
> "controller"=>"contacts", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"} params email:
> params email:   params email:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email is nested into a `contact` hash. Try this

```
params["contact"]["email"]
```

### Previous Answer

String and symbols are treated as different keys by default.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> h = { email: "symbol", "email" => "string"}
=> {:email=>"symbol", "email"=>"string"}
irb(main):002:0> h[:email]
=> "symbol"
irb(main):003:0> h["email"]
=> "string"
irb(main):004:0> h
=> {:email=>"symbol", "email"=>"string"}
irb(main):005:0>
```

However, in Rails a params hash should support indifferent access but just to be sure I would try to access the key as string

```rb
params["email"]
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html
https://medium.com/@lcriswell/ruby-symbols-vs-strings-248842529fd9

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunatley, nothing seems to work. Amended my question above.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: That was it. Can't believe I missed it. Thanks! `[:contact][:email]` is good too.